# Scroll a div vertically with the mouse wheel using javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used the following property on a div in my css

**overflow-y:scroll;**

And the vertical scroll is showing too but i need to scroll the div using the mouse wheel currently as i scroll on the div, the whole page scrolls.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: It shouldn't act this way, you sure you are adding `overflow-y:scroll` to the element? can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Scroll is not working with mouse wheel that is my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```css
/* html, body {
    height:100%;
} */
 .message_wrap {
    height:500px;
}
.message_box {
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    background-color: #B0E0E6;
    padding: 10px;
    width:350px;
    max-height:20%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.message {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="message_wrap">
    <div class="message_box">
        <p class="message">Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI.</p>
        <p class="message">Completely synergize resource sucking relationships via premier niche markets. Professionally cultivate one-to-one customer service with robust ideas. Dynamically innovate resource-leveling customer service for state of the art customer service..</p>
        <p class="message">Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value. Quickly maximize timely deliverables for real-time schemas. Dramatically maintain clicks-and-mortar solutions without functional solutions.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How you know what is the HTML content?!

Comment: how to scroll div with mouse wheel, i have added the code but its not scrolling